# Post in Wall Photos - Facebook Open Graph - Php Sdk

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I would like to publish a picture into the album "Wall Photos" if it exists, otherwise if "Wall Photos" doesn't exists publish the image without album ( APPNAME PHOTOS ).

```
$album = $facebook->api('/'PAGEID'/albums'); 
foreach($album['data'] as $album){
 if($album['name'] == 'Wall Photos'){ 
  $album_post = $album['id']; 
 }
}
$risultato['pagina'][$pagina['id']] = $facebook->api('/'.$album_post.'/photos', 'POST',           array( 'access_token' => PAGETOKEN, 'source' => '@' . IMAGE, 'message' => TEXT ) );
if(!isset($album_post)){
 $risultato['pagina'][$pagina['id']] = $facebook->api('/'.$pagina['id'].'/photos',   'POST', array(
                'access_token'  => $pagina['token'],
                'source' => '@' . IMAGEPATH,
                'message' => TEXT
        )
    );
    }else{
   $risultato['pagina'][$pagina['id']] = $facebook->api('/'.$album_post.'/photos', 'POST', array(
                'access_token'  => $pagina['token'],
                'source' => '@' . realpath("../img_post/".$post['Immagine']),
                'message' => $post['Testo']
        )
    );
    }
```

But i receive that error: Invalid album id thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1237

Comment: @MohitBumb
Output:
["name"]=>
  string(11) "Wall Photos"
  ["cover_photo"]=>
  string(15) "474591189233536"
  ["privacy"]=>
  string(6) "custom"
  ["count"]=>
  int(8)
  ["type"]=>
  string(13) "friends_walls"
  ["created_time"]=>
  string(24) "2012-05-07T13:24:03+0000"
  ["updated_time"]=>
  string(24) "2012-10-12T11:18:05+0000"
  ["can_upload"]=>
  bool(false)
}

Comment: @MohitBumb And how can i get id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id field should be an element of the $album object. In fact, its the first one.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Incidently, you should also use the BREAK command, to escape from your foreach loop when the condition has been met.

```
foreach($album['data'] as $album){
 if($album['name'] == 'Wall Photos'){ 

// To debug:

echo "<pre>";
print_r($album);
echo "</pre>";

// End debug

  $album_post = $album['id']; 
  break; 
 }
 }
```

This should produce something like:

```
Array
(
[id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[from] => Array
    (
        [category] => Community
        [name] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    )

[name] => xxxxxxxxxx
[description] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[link] => http://www.facebook.com/album.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[cover_photo] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[privacy] => everyone
[count] => 4
[type] => normal
[created_time] => 2012-12-11T14:56:06+0000
[updated_time] => 2012-12-11T14:56:22+0000
[can_upload] => 1
)
```

That should at least give you a clue as to what is going on.